# Confusing missing $

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, align

Can anyone help with this.
I'm not sure at all what I'm doing wrong but i get an error
Missing $ inserted.
 
                $
on the 2nd line with c)\

The rest of the text works fine and there are no $ signs that are not already paired in previous parts

```
\noindent
c)\\
coordinates = (99,85),(190,220),(286,383)\\
\begin{align}
error&= \left | y-(a+bx) \right |\\
E&= \left | y-(475.5+1.253x) \right |\\
(99,85):
E&=\left | 85-(475.5-1.253(99) \right |\\
&=\left | 85-(351.5) \right |\\
&=266.5\\
(190,220):
E&=\left | 220-(475.5-1.253(190) \right |\\
&=\left | 220-(237.5) \right |\\
&=17.5\\
(286,383):
E&=\left | 383-(475.5-1.253(286) \right |\\
&=\left | 386-(117.2) \right |\\
&=265.8\\
\end{align}
$\therefore$ \text{Next location is "The Reservoir" at (190,220)}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I feel that i must be missing something but have already search several sites and tried several changes to no avail

Comment: You don't need `$` inside `align`; use `&=` to `align` at the `=`. Also, welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please don't put 'urgent' in your question title. It is meaningless at best, offensive at worse. It gives no help for figuring out the content of your question, is useless to future users searching for help, and merely tries to give an erroneous sense of importance to *your* question as opposed to those of others. If the issue is really urgent, putting some effort into clarifying your question would be a better use of your time than adding meaningless clutter to its title.

Comment: Down-voters: please do not down-vote beyond -1. A score of -1 is quite sufficient to communicate the fact that the question needs improvement. Down-voting further is simply an unnecessary expression of hostility. Especially given the fact that this is a first post: much better to leave a comment suggesting how the question might be improved.

Comment: Sorry, was trying to show pryzemylaw the question as i i kept getting the same error after changing it.
Should i post the question again with edits if i get the same error after editing?

Comment: The problem is we need a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Without that, the question is not well formed. As you've seen, it is possible for people to fix the code you've posted without fixing the problem. Posting an MWE makes that much less likely. (It doesn't guarantee it but it helps. A lot.)

Comment: @cfr `\text` will work in both modes: it's got the same behaviour in that sense as `\mbox`.

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks. I was convinced I'd tested that but I can't have. (And I certainly didn't know you could use it in maths mode.) I've deleted my comment and updated the edit to my question (to just note that it is unnecessary here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\therefore` is not a text command. It needs to be in maths mode e.g. `$\therefore$`. In your snipped, it is outside the `align` environment and therefore in text mode which won't work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}


\begin{document}
\noindent
c)\\
coordinates = (99,85),(190,220),(286,383)\\
\begin{align}
error&= \left | y-(a+bx) \right |\\
E&= \left | y-(475.5+1.253x) \right |\\
(99,85):
E&=\left | 85-(475.5-1.253(99) \right |\\
&=\left | 85-(351.5) \right |\\
&=266.5\\
(190,220):
E&=\left | 220-(475.5-1.253(190) \right |\\
&=\left | 220-(237.5) \right |\\
&=17.5\\
(286,383):
E&=\left | 383-(475.5-1.253(286) \right |\\
&=\left | 386-(117.2) \right |\\
&=265.8
\end{align}
$\therefore$ Next location is ``The Reservoir'' at (190,220)

\end{document}
```

[image: align followed by therefore]

## EDIT

You do not need `\text{}` for `Next location...` as that is in text mode anyway i.e. it is not text inside a maths environment which is what you normally use `\text{}` for. [In light of Joseph Wright's comment] This won't cause an error but it is unnecessary.

Comment: @JulianDezGilroy Don't accept my answer if it didn't work! People will pay less attention to your question. (When you have more reputation, you can upvote answers without accepting them but you cannot do that yet.) I recommend unaccepting my answer and editing your question to include a proper [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) which can be used to reproduce the problem. This is much more likely to get you help than posting a link to somewhere else, especially if people have to trawl through a long document in order to find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

All your `$`'s inside `align` should be replaced by `&`'s.

(You snippet is not a MWE, hence version without corrections and the final result).

Comment: I edited it to how it currently is on Latex and i still get the same error,
If i try to put a $ sign at the c)\\ where says its missing, my \align no longer works as it can't work in maths mode.

Do you have any idea how i could fix it.
Sorry if i'm bothering with dumb questions.

Comment: @JulianDezGilroy Does the code I posted give you errors? If so, there is something wrong with your TeX installation. If not, but you continue to get errors in your main document, the problem lies elsewhere in your document. In that case, you will definitely need to provide a Minimum Working Example people can compile to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JulianDezGilroy Now only `text` is unneeded in `\text{Next location is "The Reservoir" at (190,220)}`, because you are in text mode, and `\text` is used inside math.

Comment: I'm afraid  i still get the same error, 
It works if i put it on a separate document but doesn't want to work if i put it at the end of the original doc.

All the rest of the text works perfectly and the Math mode signs are paired up in it. 

I might just resort to printing it as a separate page if it's too complicated.

Comment: https://www.writelatex.com/1668037kxgsvr#/4157018/
here is text if that helps