# Error missing $

Tags: errors

Hello I've been having a "Missing $ inserted" on my latex document and i'm not sure what to do.
I've tried asking previously but wasn't able to fix it.

I'm not sure at all what I'm doing wrong but i get an error Missing $ inserted. $ on the 2nd line with c)\

The text works fine separately but when put with the rest of the document i keep on getting errors.

The rest of the text works fine and there are no $ signs that are not already paired in previous parts

```
\noindent
c)\\
coordinates = (99,85),(190,220),(286,383)\\
\begin{align}
error&= \left | y-(a+bx) \right |\\
E&= \left | y-(475.5+1.253x) \right |\\
(99,85):
E&=\left | 85-(475.5-1.253(99) \right |\\
&=\left | 85-(351.5) \right |\\
&=266.5\\
(190,220):
E&=\left | 220-(475.5-1.253(190) \right |\\
&=\left | 220-(237.5) \right |\\
&=17.5\\
(286,383):
E&=\left | 383-(475.5-1.253(286) \right |\\
&=\left | 386-(117.2) \right |\\
&=265.8\\
\end{align}
$\therefore$ \text{Next location is "The Reservoir" at (190,220)}
\end{document}
```

This is link to writeLatex online document https://www.writelatex.com/1668037kxgsvr#/4157018/

Is anyone able to help with this?
Error is at end.

Comment: You are writing `\text{}` outside math environment. Use `$\therefore$ Next location is "The Reservoir" at (190,220)`

Comment: @HarishKumar See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208555/confusing-missing. Indeed, that is the problem. Or, rather, it seems it might not be the problem but it is all terribly unclear as there is no MWE. All we have is the assurance that the remainder of the document is not the problem and that posting my code does not work with the remainder of the document even though it works on its own (it does not use `\text{}` outside maths mode). <shrug>

Comment: When I run the example code at the writelatex site I don't get an error message? Have you maybe changed the code in the meantime? If so, you should update your posting accordingly.

Comment: After your questions are reformatted (so that they at the very least include an immutable MWE) and you get at least one answer that fixes your problem, they will probably need to be merged.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at the [guide for how to minimalize your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225).

Answer (score 5):

The error is earlier. In your code from https://www.writelatex.com/1668037kxgsvr#/4157018/ just after the line 250 you have `\begin{matrix}`. Commenting it makes the document compilable.

(A MWE with this fragment can help the future visitors).